# Row operations in determinants

Tags: determinant

How to prove that by adding to a row a multiple of another row, the determinant remains  the same ?

Comment: You mean *adding* a row...

Comment: @DavidMitra ... of a _matrix_

Comment: I mean adding a row of a determinant of a matrix with a multiple of a second row or a column with a multiple of a second column

Comment: @Fifi A determinant is a single number. It doesn't have rows. What you mean is "Adding a multiple of one row of a matrix to another row of that matrix".

Comment: ok you understood what I mean

Comment: @Arthur It is written in my book "we call row(resp.column)of det(A) every row (resp. Column) of A."

Comment: Well, ok, then. If it's a defined term, you may use it. I just haven't seen it used that way before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that $$\Delta = \begin{vmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & a_3\\ b_1 & b_2 & b_3\\ c_1 & c_2 & c_3\end{vmatrix}\tag{1}$$ $$\Rightarrow \text{ (Performing }R_1 \to R_1 + kR_2) \, \, \Delta_1 = \begin{vmatrix} a_1 + kb_1 & a_2+kb_2 & a_3 + kb_3\\ b_1 & b_2 & b_3\\ c_1 & c_2 & c_3\end{vmatrix} \text{ (say) }$$ $$\Rightarrow \Delta_1 = \begin{vmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & a_3\\ b_1 & b_2 & b_3\\ c_1 & c_2 & c_3\end{vmatrix} + \begin{vmatrix} kb_1 & kb_2 & kb_3\\ b_1 & b_2 & b_3\\ c_1 & c_2 & c_3\end{vmatrix}$$ $$\Rightarrow \Delta_1 = \begin{vmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & a_3\\ b_1 & b_2 & b_3\\ c_1 & c_2 & c_3\end{vmatrix} + k\begin{vmatrix} b_1 & b_2 & b_3\\ b_1 & b_2 & b_3\\ c_1 & c_2 & c_3\end{vmatrix}$$ $$\Rightarrow \Delta_1 = \begin{vmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & a_3\\ b_1 & b_2 & b_3\\ c_1 & c_2 & c_3\end{vmatrix} + 0$$ $$\Rightarrow \Delta_1 = \Delta$$

Similarly, **we can show the same for any column operation**. Thus, *for any such column and row operation*, the determinant remains the same. Hope it helps.

Comment: Are you assuming the determinant is linear here?